# List files from a shared directory in a remote server

Tags: batch-file, ftp, windows-server

I need to list the files inside a shared directory in a remote windows server.
I can access the directory through command prompt: \remoteserver\dir_parent\dir_child.

I need to create a file with a list of the files in the shared directory.
I have a bat file where I try to open a connection ans list the files:

list.bat

```
FTP -v -i -s:ftp.txt
```

ftp.txt

```
open 1.1.1.1
ls /dir_parent/dir_child/ file_llist.txt
disconnect
bye
```

but doesn't work, Can you give some advice or guideline to list the files inside a shared directory in a remote server.
The remote server is a Windows machine.

Comment: What about ID and password and the paths are case sensitive so be sure that they are correct

Comment: You can access the server via a network path, so why are you trying to use FTP?

Comment: to retrieve the list of files automatically and store the name of the files in a db. I will only store the name of the file, not the whole document

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a "\remoteserver\dir_parent\dir_child\*.*" > Myfilelist.txt
```

or to do subfolders as well

```
dir /a /s "\remoteserver\dir_parent\dir_child\*.*" > Myfilelist.txt
```